# Redactor Link Encoding create 404 errors

Tags: craft3, redactor

Has anyone come across scrambled link encoding in Redactor resulting in 404 errors?

How do we solve this?

What should be: 
https://www.dazeddigital.com/​f​a​s​h​i​o​n​/​a​r​t​i​c​l​e​/​3​3​0​3​0​/​1​/​m​a​k​i​n​g​-​g​u​c​c​i​-​m​c​q​u​e​e​n​-​a​n​d​-​s​a​i​n​t​-​l​a​u​r​e​n​t​-​s​u​s​t​a​i​n​a​b​l​e​-​k​e​r​i​n​g​-​i​n​t​e​rview

Becomes:
https://www.dazeddigital.com/%E2%80%8Bf%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bs%E2%80%8Bh%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bo%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8B/%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Br%E2%80%8Bt%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bc%E2%80%8Bl%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8B/%E2%80%8B3%E2%80%8B3%E2%80%8B0%E2%80%8B3%E2%80%8B0%E2%80%8B/%E2%80%8B1%E2%80%8B/%E2%80%8Bm%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bk%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bg%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bg%E2%80%8Bu%E2%80%8Bc%E2%80%8Bc%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bm%E2%80%8Bc%E2%80%8Bq%E2%80%8Bu%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bd%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bs%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bt%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bl%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bu%E2%80%8Br%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bt%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bs%E2%80%8Bu%E2%80%8Bs%E2%80%8Bt%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Ba%E2%80%8Bb%E2%80%8Bl%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bk%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8Br%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bg%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bi%E2%80%8Bn%E2%80%8Bt%E2%80%8Be%E2%80%8Brview

Comment: Pasting the link you say it should be directly also results in a 404. I don't think the issue is with Redactor.

Comment: Man I'm confused. When I type the link below in the address bar it works. But when I copy the same URL above it doesn't. They are exactly the same. When I paste the working link below into Craft as the link it then won't work again. https://www.dazeddigital.com/fashion/article/33030/1/making-gucci-mcqueen-and-saint-laurent-sustainable-kering-interview